# Fill in Angular form using Jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, forms

I am working on an Angular form, which has many fields. I want to be able to easily populate the fields with test data, but that functionality can't be released to other environments.

So that I can test on other environments I have created a Chrome extension to populate the forms:

```
$('input:text').val('Lorem Ipsum').trigger("input");
$('input[type="email"]').val('test@test.com').trigger("input");
$('input[type="tel"]').val('0412345678').trigger("input");
```

However this does not trigger angular to re-validate the field, which still has the below classes:

```
ng-pristine ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-maxlength
```

How can I make the Angular app re-validate from outside the APP itself?